# How to get 7th date from past by excluding specific dates

Tags: mysql, date

I've prepared a MySql query to get exact 7th past date from the given date by excluding list of specific dates 
i.e.

If I'm passing date as `2016-10-21` then output'll be `2016-10-12` by excluding specific dates from given set of comma separated dates `2016-10-16,2016-10-15,2016-10-10` for this I've tried something

```
SELECT *
FROM 
table where id = 46 and 
(
startdate >= DATE_SUB("2016-10-21 00:00:00",INTERVAL 7 DAY) and 
startdate <= DATE_SUB("2016-10-21 23:59:59",INTERVAL 7 DAY) and 
startdate NOT IN ('2016-10-16 00:00:00','2016-10-15 00:00:00','2016-10-10 00:00:00')
)
```

But it doesn't seems to work as expected. How to exclude those given comma separated dates within `DATE_SUB` function

Input           : `2016-10-21` 
Expected Output : `2016-10-12`

Comment: Please show us sample input and desired output.  Your question is unclear.

Comment: You mean, going back `X` days from a give starting date and bypassing dates that are found in a pre-defined list?

Comment: Yes @FDavidov thats what I'm looking for but right now that `X = 7`

Answer (score 1):

First I would substract from today's date, each of the excluding dates. If the results are <=7, I would increment 'c' counter for each.

Finally, I'd just have to add 'c' to '7', and make a simple DATE_SUB with the origin date and the result of adding 7 to the counter.